# Separar o valor da string

Tags: php, jquery

Colegas.

Ao calcular o frete do carrinho, ele está retornando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber, como faço para pegar somente o valor **24.90**? Pois preciso somar com o valor do carrinho. Veja abaixo os códigos referentes:

**PHP**

```
$parametros = http_build_query($parametros);
    $url = 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx';
    $curl = curl_init($url.'?'.$parametros);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $dados = curl_exec($curl);
    $dados = simplexml_load_string($dados);

    foreach($dados->cServico as $linhas) {
        if($linhas->Erro == 0) {
            echo str_replace(",",".",$linhas->Valor) .'</br>';
            echo "<strong>Prazo de entrega:</strong> ".$linhas->PrazoEntrega. "Dias </br>";
        }else {
            echo $linhas->MsgErro;
        }
```

**JQUERY**

```
ajax1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax1.readyState == 4) {
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ajax1.responseText;
           valorFrete = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;

           vv = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML + valorFrete;
           valorTotal = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = vv.toFixed(2);

        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Aguarde, calculando...";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faz isso do lado cliente (no js), podes simplesmente fazer:

```js
responseText = '24.95, <strong> Outro texto, </strong>'; // faz de conta
valorFrete = parseFloat(responseText)
alert(valorFrete);
```

Desta maneira já tens o valor númerico, pronto para operações matemáticas.

Nota que isto só resulta se tiveres a certeza que o primeiro caracter será sempre um digito.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode quebrar a *string* por vírgula nesse caso, e pegar o primeiro índice:

```js
let texto = '24.95, <strong> Outro texto, </strong>';
let valor = texto.split(',');
console.log(valor[0]);
```